# What's a quaternion rotation?

Tags: 3d, rotation, quaternions, angle

Is quaternion rotation just a vector with X,Y,Z which the object will rotate towards, and a roll which turns the object on its axis?

Is it that simple?

Meaning if you have X=0, Z=0 and Y=1 the object will face upwards?
And if you have Y=0, Z=0 and X=1 the object will face to the right?

(assuming X right, Y up and Z depth)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A quaternion has 4 components, which can be related to an angle θ and an axis vector **n**. The rotation will make the object rotate about the axis **n** by an angle θ.

For example, if we have an cube like

```
 ______
|\  6  \
| \_____\     z
|5 |    | : y ^
 \ | 4  |    \|
  \|____|     +--> x
```

Then a rotation of 90° about the axis (x=0, y=0, z=1) will rotate the "5" face from the left to the front.

```
 ______
|\  6  \
| \_____\      z
|3 |    | :  x ^
 \ | 5  |     \|
  \|____|  y<--+
```

(Note: This is the axis/angle description of rotation, which is what OP confuses. For how quaternion is applied to rotation, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)

Comment: @clamp: Depends on if the system is left-handed or right-handed.

Comment: the OP said "Y up and Z depth".

Comment: @LarsH: Put your head below the z-axis, and view the whole thing in a mirror. :)

Comment: This was so simply explained and yet perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

A [quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) in general is an extension of a complex number into 4 dimensions.  So no, they are not just x, y, and z, and an angle, but they're close. More below...

Quaternions can be used to [represent rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), so they're useful for graphics:

> Unit quaternions provide a convenient
>   mathematical notation for representing
>   orientations and rotations of objects
>   in three dimensions. Compared to Euler
>   angles they are simpler to compose and
>   avoid the problem of gimbal lock.
>   Compared to rotation matrices they are
>   more numerically stable and may be
>   more efficient.

So what are the 4 components and [how do they relate to the rotation?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#The_hypersphere_of_rotations)

> The [unit quaternion] point (w,x,y,z) represents a
>   rotation around the axis directed by
>   the vector (x,y,z) by an angle alpha
>   = 2 cos<sup>-1</sup> w = 2 sin<sup>-1</sup> sqrt(x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>+z<sup>2</sup>).

So back to your question,

> Meaning if you have X=0, Z=0 and Y=1
>   the object will face upwards?

No... the object will rotate around this `<0,1,0>` vector, i.e. it will rotate around the y axis, turning counterclockwise as seen from above, if your graphics system uses right-hand rotation. (And if we plug in w = sqrt(1 - (0 + 1 + 0)), your unit quaternion is (0,0,1,0), and it will rotate by angle 2 cos<sup>-1</sup>0, = 2 * 90 degrees = 180 degrees or pi radians.)

> And if you have Y=0, Z=0 and X=1 the object will face to the right?

This will rotate around the vector `<1,0,0>`, the x axis, so it will rotate counterclockwise as seen from the positive x direction (e.g. right). So the top would turn forward (180 degrees, so it would rotate until it faced downward).