# What is a quaternion? And how is it used in graphics?

Tags: opengl, graphics, quaternions

I've seen other stackoverflow answers such as

[What's a quaternion rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023161)

but I'm still not sure what they are

When I looked it up on Wikipedia, it gave me a 4-dimensional imaginary coordinate space.

Can anyone explain to me what they are in the most intuitive sense please? And how they are used in computer graphics?

Answer (score 0):

A Quaternion is a 3D vector with a rotation. For using them in OpenGL, I found a link for you: [OpenGL Rotations](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/)